# Bash codes with some time-conditions

Tags: bash, shell-script

How is Bash code to run a binary or command else with some time-conditions eg. pseudocode

```
if time is between 6:00 - 9:00 run foo.sh

else if time is between 9:00 - 12:00 run bar.sh

else run foobar.sh
```

Please help out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hour=$(date +%k)
if ((hour >= 6 && hour < 9)); then
    ./foo.sh
elif ((hour >= 9 && hour <= 12)); then
    ./bar.sh
else
    ./foobar.sh
fi
```

---

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

A `POSIX` version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

hour=$(date +%H)

if [ "$hour" -ge 6 ] && [ "$hour" -lt 9 ]; then
    ./foo.sh
elif [ "$hour" -ge 9 ] && [ "$hour" -lt 12 ]; then
    ./bar.sh
else
    ./foobar.sh
fi
```

or

```
case "$hour" in
    ( 0[6-8]      ) echo '6:00 TO 8:59'  ;;
    ( 09 | 1[0-1] ) echo '9:00 TO 11:59' ;;
    ( *           ) echo 'rest'          ;;
esac
```

Comment: Your code will fail between 08.00 and 09.59 because the hour will be `08` or `09`. This is because the `bash` treats integers with a leading zero as octal, and neither `08` nor `09` is valid octal. You should use `%k` instead of `%H` or strip any leading zero in the comparison with `${hour#0}`

Comment: If you'd used `if [ ${hour#0} -ge 6 ] && [ ${hour#0} -lt 9 ]; then`, etc. and stuck with `date +%H` your code would have been POSIX compliant too

Comment: @roaima, for `[`/`test` POSIX requires the operands to arithmetic operators to be interpreted as decimal even if they start with a zero. Invoking split+glob on those doesn't make sense. `hour=$(date +%H); [ "$hour" -ge 6 ]...` is more portable as some `[` implementations don't like the leading space that `%k` introduces for hours before 10.

Comment: Note that with GNU `date`, you can also use `date +%-k` or `date +%-H` to get the hour with leading space or 0.

Comment: With `bash`, see also `printf -v hour '%(%k)T' -1` (also `%-k` on GNU systems at least) to avoid the fork+pipe and invocation of separate `date` utility.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `bash` treats the values as octal

Comment: @roaima, not with `[`. `[ 010 -eq 10 ]` is true as POSIX requires, `[[ 010 -eq 8 ]]` is true like in older versions of ksh IIRC

Answer (score 0):

Your logic needs to be more precise, Your first if states 09:00 and your second if states 09:00.  The first should be 08:59? or second should be 09:01?  Lets use the date function without the ":" so you can use that in the compare as hhmm (without padding of zero on the hour)

`timenow=$(date +%k%M)`. then issue the if as stated by Gilles above but compare >=600 && <= 859 and >= 900 && <=1159